# Word translation tool with mouse click?

Tags: windows, translation

I am learning Spanish. And I read texts in Spanish on my computer (normally PDFs) where I want to translate words I don't understand with a click of my mouse.

It takes way too much time to copy the unknown word into the clipboard, switch contexts, paste it in a translator and switch back.

What tool can I use to translate Spanish into English or German that offers an acceptable vocabulary?

Comment: So, are you asking for a tool that can work with PDFs?  That seems to be an extra step, pdf->text then translate the text.

Comment: I am asking for a tool that can handle any textual input, not just a text editor, but PDFs, Word documents, ... Of course translating texts in images is not my requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [Lingoes](http://www.lingoes.net/) for on-screen translation with lots of free dictionaries:

[image: Lingoes popup window]

It comes along with text capture plugins for Firefox, Chrome and Acrobat / Acrobat Reader.

**HINT:** You should run Lingoes as Administrator for the first time to be able to install the Acrobat plugin.

You can configure which action triggers the translation popup:

[image: Lingoes Configuration Window]

Comment: Not bad but it does not detect the language automatically, right? So I have to switch every time when translating from different languages. I am used to automatic detection in [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator), QTranslate suggested by Саша Черных does this better.

Comment: @MichaelS. Thanks for bringing this up again. Lingoes can search multiple dictionaries at once. The advantage of QTranslate is, that it does not require all these additional text capture plugins.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Choice

[image: QTranslate] [**QTranslate**](https://quest-app.appspot.com/) — is my choice.

---

### 2. Demonstration

[image: Demo]

---

### 3. Some features

1. Free;
2. Active development;
3. Auto-detect languages for translation support;
4. [**Support 9 translation services**](https://quest-app.appspot.com/languages). User may select translation via any of these services.
5. [**XDXF offline dictionaries**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdxf/) support;
6. Spellchecking. [**Multi-lingual spellchecking**](https://thenextweb.com/google/2015/08/22/chrome-can-now-spellcheck-multiple-languages-simultaneously/) for Google Translate.
7. Translating in QTranslate window (see GIF). User open QTranslate window → print or paste text for translation → user get real-time output.
8. Translating in tooltip (see GIF). User select text → press hotkey for translation in tooltip → user get output in tooltip.
9. Replace selection text for translation (see GIF). User select text → press hotkey → selection text replace for translation.

---

For more features see [**QTranslate official site**](https://quest-app.appspot.com/home).

Comment: unfortunately the official site is down these days, though its copy and the app can still be downloaded from web-archive