# Automatically translate the words in a Japanese document as I pass the mouse cursor over them

Tags: osx, translation, language

Is there software I can install on my Mac with OS X 10.6.8 which will automatically translate the words on a PDF/Word/Excel(/other) document as I pass the mouse cursor over them?

This sort of thing seems to exist for reading internet sites (for example [Rikai-kun](http://code.google.com/p/rikaikun/)), but I would like to use it on documents such as PDF files.   Ideally, it would work offline (while not connected to the internet).

Comment: As a workaround you can convert pdfs to html and then use rikai-kun/chan. I quickly tried that with a free online converter and ran into no problems.

Comment: Related: [Word translation tool with mouse click?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/214/185)

Comment: @Izzy: Thanks I'll check this but I want to find something that does use the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any 3rd party software for it.

1. Open Dictionary application.
2. Press Command+, to open Dictionary preferences.
3. Select Japanese dictionary.
4. Congratulations, now you have system dictionary which will translate a word into either direction by simply doing "look up" gesture either by right-click menu or by three finger tap on a word or selected phrase.

Comment: This an excellent find thank you. (Actually I already use the dictionary but the wrong setting. Just for reference the Contextual menu has to be set to "Open dictionary application". Also my PC is two-finger click on the word.)

Comment: FYR: I am still hoping to find something that will provide the info when curser moves over a word so I shall hold off accepting for a while.

Comment: I think Babylon provides such feature, at least on Windows. Not sure about Mac.